# 400 Bad Request` response: error: bad_request,reason:Referer header required

Tags: php, couchdb, guzzle, laravel-5.4

I am trying insert the documents into a database in couchdb. 
But I get error as

**Client error: `POST http://localhost:5984/login/new_document` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Referer header required."}**

Here is my code

```
public function guzzle_insert_doc()
{
    $client = new Client(); 

    $val=array(array(" _id " => " Raju ") , array(" age " => " 23 ") ,array(" Designation " => " Designer " ));     
    $val= json_encode($val);
    //echo $val;
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost:5984/login/new_document',[
            'json' => $val 
        ]);
    $code = $res->getBody()->getContents();

    return $code;   
}
```

Here is I tried another way but still I get error

```
public function guzzle_insert_doc()
{
    $client = new Client();     
    $res = $client->request('PUT', 'http://localhost:5984/login/new_doc',[
            "uname" => "admin",
            "password" => "admin123"  

        ]);


    //return $res;
}
```